# Trying to create a simple button on kivy, but gave me an error " Only one root object is allowed by .kv"

Tags: python, kivy, kivymd

This is what i've imported on this app, i'm following a tutorial on YT:

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp   
from kivy.lang import Builder
```

the part where i create the button/rectangular button:

```
KV = """

Screen:

MDRectangleFlatButton:

    text:"Hello Kivy World"
    
    pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.5, "center_y": 0,5 }

            """
```

The remaining code:

```
class MainApp(MDApp):
    
    def build(self):
        self.title = "hello kivy"
        self.theme_cls.theme_style = "Dark"
        self.theme_cls.primary_palette = "Red"
        return Builder.load_string(KV)
        
MainApp().run()
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: always put FULL error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information in the full error/traceback.

Comment: `Screen:` and `MDRectangleFlatButton:` both create root widget. You should remove one of them, or you should put one of them in `< >` like `<Screen>:`. See kivy documentation for `kv` and [rule context](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/guide/lang.html#rule-context)

Comment: If you want the `MDRectangleFlatButton` to be in your `Screen`, then it must be indented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should fix it.

```
KV = """

<Screen>

    MDRectangleFlatButton:

        text:"Hello Kivy World"
    
        pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.5, "center_y": 0,5 }

            """
```